# ATI driver for Radeon 6530D

Tags: ati, radeon

After installing Ubuntu on a machine with a Radeon 6530D graphics card, the machine will reboot to a black screen because of problems with the default graphics driver.

How do I install the proprietary ATI driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I installed the ATI driver for Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04.

1. Reboot. When the black screen appears, press some of the cursor
   keys and a box will appear with a message about an X server error.
2. Press CTRL + ALT + F1 to get a tty terminal.
3. Log in as root. The password is your own password that you set during installation.
4. Remove the Xorg drivers. `apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon`
5. Reboot.
6. Repeat steps 1-3.
7. `apt-get update`
8. `apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle-updates`
9. `aticonfig --initial`
10. Reboot.

You should now have a working desktop. You will find the AMD Catalyst Control Centre in the menu, although I have never found a need to change any of the settings.

Comment: Same answer with block code formatting + markdown : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10729769/